# Finding a positive definite symmetric bilinear function .

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, representation-theory

Could anyone give me a hint about solving this problem please?

[image]

**EDIT:**
I am adding this for the comments of @David, I think he is speaking about this theorem:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The usual thing to do is average over the group: Take $(\cdot,\cdot)$ to be the dot product and define $$\langle v, w\rangle=\frac{1}{3}((v,w)+(Tv,Tw)+(T^2v,T^2w))$$

Comment: I know that the elements of $Z_{3}$ are {1,2,3} ..... then how will I use the given matrix .... the generator of $Z$ is 1 ..... what does it mean for the generator to go into the linear operator ...... why you wrote the inner product of v and w like this ? ..... I will add the formula for the averaging that I know in the question above (which I actually do not understand how to use it)@DavidHill

Comment: I know that for the reals with orthonormal basis the positive definite symmetric bilinear function is just the dot product.... but how can I use this information ? @DavidHill

Comment: Do you understand what a representation of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ is? Do you understand what a $T$-invariant means?

Comment: yes I understand yes I know ..... but I do not know how to apply the definitions?@DavidHill

Comment: @DavidHill I have edited my question .... I think because of this theorem you have written the above inner product and you is applying it to the elements of the group which are $\{0,1,2\}$ am I correct?

Comment: but I do not know what are the vectors $v$ and $w$ that I will use in calculating this inner product?@DavidHill

Comment: I took $T$ to mean $T(1)=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}$. You should interpret $T^2=T(2)=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}^2$. Take $v=\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}$ and $w=\begin{pmatrix}c\\d\end{pmatrix}$. Though, you should be able to give a proof that $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is $T$-invariant without choosing coordinates. You will, of course, need to check that $I=T(0)=T(3)=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(\cdot,\cdot):\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be the usual dot product and define
$$
\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$$
by
$$\langle v, w\rangle=\frac{1}{3}(\langle T(0)v, T(0)w\rangle+\langle T(1)v, T(1)w\rangle+\langle T(2)v, T(2)w\rangle).
$$
Note that
\begin{align}
\langle T(i)v, T(i)w\rangle&=\frac{1}{3}(\langle T(0)T(i)v, T(0)T(i)w\rangle+\langle T(1)T(i)v, T(1)T(i)w\rangle+\langle T(2)T(i)v, T(2)T(i)w\rangle)\\
&=\frac{1}{3}(\langle T(0+i)v, T(0+i)w\rangle+\langle T(1+i)v, T(1+i)w\rangle+\langle T(2+i)v, T(2+i)w\rangle)\\
&=\frac{1}{3}(\langle T(0)v, T(0)w\rangle+\langle T(1)v, T(1)w\rangle+\langle T(2)v, T(2)w\rangle)\\
&=\langle v,w\rangle.
\end{align}
It follows that $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is $T$-invariant. To see that it is nondegenerate, let $\displaystyle v=\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}$ and compute directly that $\langle v,v\rangle=\frac{2}{3}(a^2+b^2+(a-b)^2)$. Therefore, $\langle v,v\rangle >0$ unless $a=b=0$.